# Disable echo in GNU readline to input a password

Tags: c, readline

I'm using GNU readline in C to input a username and password from the user. How can I disable echo so the password doesn't appear on the screen?

There are examples around the net of using readline in Perl and setting the ReadMode to "noecho", but I have not seen a C example of that.

I looked into using `getpass()`, but the manual page has this warning:

> This function is obsolete. Do not use it.

It comes with no further information about what we should use instead.